# Function updateDoc() called with invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported (found in document)

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a subcollection in my firestore and I'm trying to update the data in the modal. I noticed if I add more than one state to update, I get the "Function updateDoc() called with invalid data"...

Here's my code snippet:-

```js
import { doc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import EditNoteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EditNote';
import { db } from '../../firebase';


const EditInvngs = ({id, name, date, doctor, status}) => {

    const [createDate, setCreateDate] = useState([date])
    const [createName, setCreateName] = useState([name])
    const [createDoctor, setCreateDoctor] = useState([doctor])
    const [createStatus, setCreateStatus] = useState([status])


    const {userId} = useParams();
    console.log(userId)


  const updateData = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      const taskDocument = doc(db, "dentist/" + userId , "investigations", id);
      await updateDoc(taskDocument, {
        name: createName,
        doctor: createDoctor,
        date: createDate,
        status: createStatus,
      });
      window.location.reload();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }


  }
  return (
   <>
        {/* Modal Button */}
        <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target={`#id${id}`}>
        <EditNoteIcon/>
      </button>

        
      <div
        className="modal fade"
        id={`id${id}`}
        tabIndex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="editLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="editLabel" style={{color:"grey"}}>
                Update Investigations</h5>
              <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">

              <input
      type="text"
      className="form-control"
      placeholder="enter investigation here..."
      defaultValue={createName}
      onChange={(e) => setCreateName(e.target.value)}
      size="3080"
    />
    <input
      type="date"
      className="form-control"
      defaultValue={createDate}
      onChange={(e) => setCreateDate(e.target.value)}
    />
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Consultant doctor.."
      className="form-control"
      defaultValue={createDoctor}
      onChange={(e) => setCreateDoctor(e.target.value)}
      size="3080"
    />
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="enter status here.."
      className="form-control"
      defaultValue={createStatus}
      onChange={(e) => setCreateStatus(e.target.value)}
      size="3080"
    />
            

            </div>

              <div className="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={e => updateData(e)}
              >Update Investigation</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

   </>
  )
}

export default EditInvngs
```

When I tried to use only one state in the updateDoc, for instance, using only "name" as an update it works perfectly but the moment I add more than one state it throws the error..

Here's what I mean...

```
  const updateData = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
          const taskDocument = doc(db, "dentist/" + userId , "investigations", id);
          await updateDoc(taskDocument, {
            name: createName,
          });
          window.location.reload();
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }


      }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you just remove`[ ]` from `useState()`, example `const [createDate, setCreateDate] = useState(date);` And can you share the data types of objects you are using in taskDocument? also add the snippet you are using to create document?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Roopa asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @RoopaM removing [ ] solved the problem.. Why's that??

Comment: I shared a reason as answer, can you have a look at it?

Comment: I've seen it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for confirming it,If that worked and helped you resolve your issue you can acknowledge it as  answer. so other community member facing similar issue can benefit from this. if not then we can solve further.

Comment: I've done that.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState()` with braces `[ ]` will return array values, and firestore does not have nested arrays as primitive types. Hence removing `[ ]` will solve the problem. So modify your snippet as below

```
const [createDate, setCreateDate] = useState(date);
const [createName, setCreateName] = useState(name);
const [createDoctor, setCreateDoctor] = useState(doctor);
const [createStatus, setCreateStatus] = useState(status);
```

Reference: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#usestate